# JavaScript runtime error: 'Blur' is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I have been trying to get my text to watermark in my Textbox and have been coming up to some issues.

Do i have to reference `onblur` and also `onfocus` somewhere in my code because it breaks when i try and click on the Textbox in question.

This is my code and it just breaks when i click on the textbox.

**HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_Username" onfocus="Focus(this.id,'Username')" onblur="Blur(this.id,'Username')" CssClass="WaterMarkedTextBox">Username</asp:TextBox>
```

**Script**

```
window.Focus = function (objname, waterMarkText) {
 obj = document.getElementById(objname);
   if (obj.value == waterMarkText) {
    obj.value = "";
    obj.className = "NormalTextBox";
    if (obj.value == "Username" || obj.value == "" || obj.value == null) {
        obj.style.color = "black";
    }
  }
}

window.Blur = function (objname, waterMarkText) {
 obj = document.getElementById(objname);
  if (obj.value == "") {
    obj.value = waterMarkText;
    if (objname != "txtPwd") {
        obj.className = "WaterMarkedTextBox";
    }
    else {
        obj.className = "WaterMarkedTextBoxPSW";
    }
}
else {
    obj.className = "NormalTextBox";
}

if (obj.value == "Username" || obj.value == "" || obj.value == null) {
    obj.style.color = "gray";
 }
}
```

**CSS**

```
       .WaterMarkedTextBox
    {
        height: 16px;
        width: 168px;
        padding: 2px 2 2 2px;
        border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
        background-color: #F0F8FF;
        color: gray;
        font-size: 8pt;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .WaterMarkedTextBoxPSW
    {
        background-position: center;
        height: 16px;
        width: 168px;
        padding: 2px 2 2 2px;
        border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
        background-color: #F0F8FF;
        color: white;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: right;
        background-image: url(Images/psw_wMark.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .NormalTextBox
    {
        height: 16px;
        width: 168px;
    }
```

EDIT:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
<link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="Scripts/LoginValidation.js" />
```

**Yes i understand this code is online**

Comment: `Yes i understand this code is online` what??

Comment: @RUJordan No before people say this isn't my code or anything. That's why i said that.

Comment: Do you get a script error?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Yes, the title states the error.

Comment: Is the `Blur` function in the global scope?

Comment: @MikeChristensen How would i know if it was, what would i need to add?

Comment: You probably want to do `obj.onblur = ...` in your JS code rather than put it in ASP or whatever that is.

Comment: @HamzaKubba What bit in my JS has asp? do you mean the HTML?

Comment: Yes. I'm saying take the onblur and onfocus out of your HTML (which runs through ASP I assume) and put them where appropriate in your JS code.

Comment: Ignore the last comment (now deleted), I confused myself. Anyway, if you add the onblur and onfocus via JS, the Blur() and Focus() functions should work since they are in the same namespace. Alternatively you can keep the HTML and change `function Blur(...) {` to `window.Blur = function(...) {`.

Comment: @HamzaKubba I tried your second way and it still says the same thing look at the edited Script code in my question is that what you mean? if so .. still doesn't work :(

Comment: First line of your JS code should be

`window.Focus = function (objname, waterMarkText) {`

note that variables are case sensitive.

Comment: @HamzaKubba Saying this now `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Focus' is undefined` and also about the `Blur`

Comment: Are you sure the JS script is getting loaded on the same page as the text box/input element?

Comment: @HamzaKubba Look at my edit at the bottom of my answer these are 2 lines in my HTML they look right?

Comment: @HamzaKubba Nevermind it was my bad put the wrong link in and i just changed and it worked. If you would like to sum up your comments as an answer i will happily accept :) Thanks for all your help!